# Spring Boot fail to stop Tomcat on actuator shutdown

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-boot-actuator

I stop Spring Boot (v2.1.7) using a script that run actuator shutdown:
`curl --noproxy "*" -XPOST -k https://127.0.0.1:8099/actuator/shutdown`

#### It fail with this exception:

```
Apr 07, 2020 9:27:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
Apr 07, 2020 9:27:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase stopInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during stop
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:982)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:469)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:254)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:309)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1032)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.ShutdownEndpoint.performShutdown(ShutdownEndpoint.java:70)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:976)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Caller provided invalid global context
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceLinkFactory.validateGlobalContext(ResourceLinkFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceLinkFactory.deregisterGlobalResourceAccess(ResourceLinkFactory.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5413)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    ... 27 more

Apr 07, 2020 9:27:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase stopInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during stop
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during stop
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:982)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:469)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:254)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:309)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1032)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.ShutdownEndpoint.performShutdown(ShutdownEndpoint.java:70)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during stop
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:990)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:976)
    ... 14 more
```

And Tomcat embedded server is not closed.
How can I solved it?

Ignore the following - just writing text here because I can't post - getting error message: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: I don't have a solution to your issue but can give some ideas. I have faced an issue with spring actuators and spring context. The issue has happened because of child context (spring actuator context) was not correct linked to the main spring context. I guess you should find out in this way.

Comment: @MaximPopov Sorry for my ignorance, can you explain how to link the spring actuator context to the main spring context. I don't know how to do it or how to check that.

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducing example? I can't reproduce your issue